# Si tengo una tienda online : ¿mis productos deberían ir dentro un <article> o un <section>?

Tags: html, seo

Imagínense por ejemplo que es una tienda online sobre lentes y en mi home muestro varios de ellos.

Se que un `article` es para enmarcar un elemento independiente, que lo pueda poner en otra pagina y siga con el mismo significado. un producto es solo un producto, es decir, es independiente y lo pudiera colocar en cualquier otra pagina de mi web sin que pierda sentido. Pero una etiqueta `section` sirve para seccionar partes que tienen el mismo sentido por ejemplo en un libro cada uno de los capítulos corresponderían a una `<section>`. y un producto en particular también es parte de todo de lo que trata mi web.

Así que tengo ese dilema porque concuerda al mismo tiempo con las dos.

Comment: Te recomiendo esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549561/section-vs-article-html5 espero te sirva

Answer (score 1):

En realidad la etiqueta no importa demasiado, en mi opinión  se usa para crear secciones de contenido y  para mostrar contenido.

```
<section class="product_list">
  <h2> Woman <h2>
  <article>
      <a>
         <img>
         <h3></h3>
         <span class="price">$</span>
      </a>
  </article>
```

Ahora lo más importante para el motor de google, sera el ROBOT.TXT, el SITEMAP, y los META que agreges a cada pagina, porque en realidad lo que le interesa a google no es saber que tienes 48 productos en una pagina, si no que ENLACES existen hay si al ingresar a estos ENLACES se tienen METAS relacionados.

Algo importante para google son los backlinks , u enlaces para llegar a la pagina, si ejemplo tiene el producto  .com/woman/pink-shirt-delivery-free , y en tus pagina de inicio tienes  botones de consulta rapida como

```
<a href="***.com?search=shirt&color=ping&gender=female">***</a>
```

que recarga tu pagina con

```
<article> <a href="**.com/woman/pink-shirt-delivery-free"></a> <article>
```

y al ingresar me muestra una pagina con un

```
 <head><meta title="Camisa para Mujer color rosa | envión gratis en españa"></head>
<h1>Camisa para Mujer</h1>
<img alt="Foto de Camisa para Mujer Color Rosa compra en ***.com">
```

Otra cosa más es la velocidad de carga de la pagina. Si ademas de buenos metas y re-direcciones eficaces aumenta tu posicionamiento el velocidad en que este contenido se muestra lo baja ( Google sabe que un usuario dará en promedio mínimo 3 clic para encontrar algo y lograr su cometido si tu pagina demora más de 3 segundos para que el robot de eso primer click, imagina que hará un humano ), el tiempo en que la carga de una pagina da la sensación de inmediatez es en promedio **1.3** seg a **2.5 seg**  y google valida muy bien eso, dado que en promedio un usuario solo se queda 13 segundos en una pagina, debes hacer que **en esos 13 segundos puedas visitar 3 paginas dentro de tu web**.

Espero te sirva esta información.